# How could I optimize this cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

When I used this cypher query

```
match p=(n)-[r*8]-(n) 
where id(n)=548  
with p 
where ALL(x IN nodes(p)[1..length(p)] WHERE SINGLE(y IN nodes(p)[1..length(p)] WHERE x=y))  
return count(p)
```

it took 51922 ms to return the result; it is really a long time. How could I optimize this cypher query? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want a simple circuit with no repeating nodes (except the start and end node).

There's an [APOC Procedure](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_graph_algorithms_work_in_progress) to get all simple paths between two nodes, with a maximum path length. It doesn't currently work when the start and end nodes are the same, but if we set the end node as any adjacent node to your start node, and filter to only keep paths of length 7 (since the paths exclude the last hop back to the start node), then we should be able to get the right answer extremely fast.

```
match (n)--[m]
with distinct n, m
call apoc.algo.allSimplePaths(n, m, '', 7) YIELD path
with path
where length(path) = 7
return count(path)
```